# Find the height due to an explosion

Tags: calculus

A dynamite explosion erupts a rock vertically upwards which at time $t$ is at height
$h = 49t-4.9\times t^2$. How high will the rock reach?

I found the velocity $u(t)=49-9.8\times t$, through the derivative of h(t),and I solved the equation $49-9.8\times t=0$ so that to find the $t$ where the rock reaches its maximum height.

Is my way of thinking correct?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Yes. We can then calculate $h$ at that $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, perhaps you can also keep in mind that since $v=\frac{dh}{dt}$, it's positive when velocity is upwards (height increasing), and negative when downwards (height decreasing). So the point where it shifts from upwards to downwards (i.e., positive to negative) is the highest point.